# Connection Refused and access forbidden by rule Errors, how to solve?

Tags: php, apache, nginx, server, cwp

Can anyone here please with those errors lines
I don't know too much about servers config

- my server is on centos and managed by CWP panel
- web server config; nginx-apache-php-cgi
- hosting Wordpress site

```
    p=138538", host: "www.example.com", referrer: "https://www.example.com/?p=138538"
2021/01/20 04:09:04 [error] 7572#7572: *183771 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 92.243.17.112, server: example.com, request: "GET /?p=138539 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://serverip:8181/?p=138539", host: "www.example.com", referrer: "https://www.example.com/?p=138539"
2021/01/20 04:09:04 [error] 7573#7573: *183773 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 92.243.17.112, server: example.com, request: "GET /?p=138540 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://serverip:8181/?p=138540", host: "www.example.com", referrer: "https://www.example.com/?p=138540"
2021/01/20 04:09:04 [error] 7573#7573: *183775 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 92.243.17.112, server: example.com, request: "GET /?p=138541 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://serverip:8181/?p=138541", host: "www.example.com", referrer: "https://www.example.com/?p=138541"
2021/01/20 04:09:04 [error] 7573#7573: *183777 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 92.243.17.112, server: example.com, request: "GET /?p=138542 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://serverip:8181/?p=138542", host: "www.example.com", referrer: "https://www.example.com/?p=138542"
2021/01/20 04:09:04 [error] 7569#7569: *183779 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 92.243.17.112, server: example.com, request: "GET /?p=138543 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://serverip:8181/?p=138543", host: "www.example.com", referrer: "https://www.example.com/?p=138543"
2021/01/20 16:49:42 [error] 13155#13155: *363777 access forbidden by rule, client: 5.62.63.82, server: example.com, request: "GET /.git//index HTTP/1.1", host: "www.example.com"
2021/01/20 19:03:24 [error] 13152#13152: *422267 access forbidden by rule, client: 84.17.46.160, server: example.com, request: "GET /.git//index HTTP/1.1", host: "www.example.com"
2021/01/20 19:34:11 [error] 13156#13156: *440164 access forbidden by rule, client: 84.17.46.160, server: example.com, request: "GET /.git//index HTTP/1.1", host: "www.example.com"
```

Answer (score 12):

The log message "access forbidden by rule" in Nginx means the request is dropped by the rules you specified in the configuration file. You should look for rules start with "Allow" or "Deny".